# How to properly add React window.addEventListener to be able to change useState via it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have tried my combinations of how to add the event listener and I just don't understand how to achieve the result now.

My goal is to bind "keydown" events to some actions that will further change component's state.

This approach somehow works, and by pressing left arrow on keyboard the count decreases.

But for some reason, the more you press the left arrow the more there are duplicated events in console, up until the point when it gets flooded.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const countDown = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(count - 1);
    console.log(count);
  }, [count]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
      if (event.code === "ArrowLeft") {
        countDown();
      }
    });
  }, [countDown]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{count}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your console gets flooded because you are creating new listeners in every effect execution...

Make sure you remove the listener in the effect cleanup function too.

```
const keyDownListener = useCallback((event) => {
   if (event.code === "ArrowLeft") {
       countDown();
   }
});
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownListener );
    
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("keydown", keyDownListener );
    }

  }, [countDown]);
```